# PyQT Painter drawing Polygons

Tags: python, pyqt, qpainter, paintevent

In my QT application I'm drawing lots of polygons like this:

I'm animating these, so some polygons will receive a new color. This animation runs 4-5 times per second.

However, calling the `paintEvent()` of the `Qt.Painter()` 4-5 times/second **redraws ALL polygons** which results in performance issues. Its only updated once a second, which is too slow. As you may see in the picture below, only some polygons in the first 12 rows needs to be updated:

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

In the QT docs I have read that you can't really save the state of the things you've already drawn. So you have to redraw everything again. Am I missing something? Is there a trick to still achieve this?

This is what my `paintEvent()` basically looks like (simplified, reduced cyclomatic complexity)

```
for y in range(len(self.array)):
  for x in range(len(self.array[0])):
    if(this): # simplified to reduce cyclomatic complexity
      painter.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(20, 0, 255)))
    elif(that):
      painter.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(175, 175, 175)))
    else:
      painter.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(0, 0, 0)))
    hexa_size = self.array[y][x]
    hexas = createHexagon(x, y, hexa_size) # external functions to calculate the hexagon size and position
    painter.drawPolygon(hexas)
painter.end()
```

call (update on each Pin change):

```
while True:
  while(stempel.readPin(0) == 0):
    QApplication.processEvents()
    time.sleep(0.01)
  self.draw_area.update() # Pin state changed, update polygons
  while(stempel.readPin(0) == 1):
    QApplication.processEvents()
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

Comment: How are you requesting the painting update?

Comment: @musicamante from inside a while loop, that waits untill a Pin state has changed. 
I edited the question.

Comment: That's not good. Blocking functions and loops should **always** be avoided in a GUI program (at least in the main thread). Use a QTimer instead.

Comment: could you provide an example on how to replace those 3 while loops with QTimers?
I have tried this before and it didn't really work out.

Comment: That would be off topic for this question. And, in any case, just create a QTimer, connect to a function that checks the *new* state against the previous one, and if it's changed, then call the update. But that's just general usage, I cannot know how you're implementing the state change of that variable, for what I know you could just use a signal instead, which would be much more straightforward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself by using a `QGraphicsScene` + `QGraphicsView`:

```
self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
self.graphicView = QGraphicsView(self.scene, self)
```

Creating a list where all polygons are being saved:

```
self.polygons = [ [0] * len(array[0]) for _ in range(len(array))]
```

Initial drawing of all polygons:

```
for y in range(len(array)):
  for x in range(len(array[0])):
    polygon_size = self.array[y][x]
    polygon = createPoly(x, y, polygon_size)
    self.polygons[y][x] = self.scene.addPolygon(polygon, QPen(Qt.NoPen), QBrush(Qt.black))
  if(y % 50 == 0): QApplication.processEvents()
```

Update rows indivudually:

```
for poly_size in active_rows:
  for active_row in active_rows[poly_size]:
    for x in range(0, len(array[0])):
      if(array[active_row][x] == int(poly_size)):
        self.polygons[active_row][x].setBrush(QBrush(QColor(20, 0, 255)))
      if(array[active_row - 2][x] > 0 and array[active_row - 2][x] == int(poly_size)):
        self.polygons[active_row - 2][x].setBrush(QBrush(QColor(175, 175, 175)))
```

Comment: Since performance might be an issue with that many objects, consider creating single instances for those two brushes and apply them accordingly. It won't improve the result drammatically, but it certainly won't hurt.

Answer (score 1):

Qt allows scheduling an update for only a portion (region) of the widget, thus optimizing the result. This requires two step:

1. calling [`update(QRect)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#update-2) with an appropriate rectangle that covers only the part of the widget that requires repainting;
2. checking the [`event.rect()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpaintevent.html#rect) and then implement painting in order to paint only that region;

If you know for sure that *only* the first X rows are going to change color, then:

```
self.draw_area.update(
    QRect(0, 0, self.draw_area.width(), <height of the repainted rows>)
```

Then, in the paintEvent:

```
if event.rect().bottom() < <height of the repainted rows>:
    rowRange = range(indexOfTheLastRowToRepaint + 1)
else:
    rowRange = range(len(self.array))
```

Note that another solution could be using QPicture, which is a way to "serialize" a QPainter in order to improve performance and avoid unnecessary computations.

```
class DrawArea(QWidget):
    cache = None
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        if not self.cache:
            self.cache = QPicture()
            cachePainter = QPainter(self.cache)
            # draw on the painter
            cachePainter.end()
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.drawPicture(0, 0, self.cache)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.cache = None
```

The code above is very minimalistic, you might create multiple QPictures for every group of row and then decide which one paint whenever you require it, even by combining the `event.rect()` checking as explained above.

The major benefit of this technique is that QPainter usually processes a QPicture pretty fast, so you don't have to do all computations required for rows, polygons, etc.

Finally, the image you provided seems very repetitive, almost like a texture. In that case, you might consider using a QPixmap for each group of rows and then create a QBrush with that QPixmap. In that case, you'll only need to call `painter.fillRect(self.rect(), self.textureBrush)`.